# quartz scheduler clustering

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I have a 2 node HA server. Node 1 is active and node 2 is standby.

I have made one application and used the quartz api to do clustering. I have made all the tables in the db.

Now do i need to run the module in both the nodes or jst node 1 so that when the node 1 goes down the application automatically starts in node 2.

The trigger and the job name should be same or different while running the module in both the nodes?

### Quartz.properties:

org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool

org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 10

org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5

org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread = true

-- Using RAMJobStore

-- if using RAMJobStore, please be sure that you comment out

-- org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix, org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass, org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource

-org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore

-- Using JobStoreTX

-- Be sure to run the appropriate script(under docs/dbTables) first to create database/tables

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX

-- Using DriverDelegate

org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate

--New conf for Clustering

org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true

org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 20000

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = MyClusteredScheduler

-- Configuring JDBCJobStore with the Table Prefix

org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_

-- Using datasource

org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = qzDS

-- Define the datasource to use

org.quartz.dataSource.qzDS.driver = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

org.quartz.dataSource.qzDS.URL = jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.172.16.147:1521:emadb0

org.quartz.dataSource.qzDS.user = BLuser

org.quartz.dataSource.qzDS.password = BLuser

org.quartz.dataSource.qzDS.maxConnections = 30

### -----------------------

Answer (score 2):

According to :
http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering

in particular :

> Clustering currently only works with the JDBC-Jobstore (JobStoreTX or JobStoreCMT), and essentially works by having each node of the cluster share the same database.
>
> Load-balancing occurs automatically, with each node of the cluster firing jobs as quickly as it can. When a trigger's firing time occurs, the first node to acquire it (by placing a lock on it) is the node that will fire it.

You should start all your nodes, the fastest will trigger the job, the others will know about it.

Comment: But when i run on both the nodes. On the second node i get an error:`Unable to store Job with name: 'JOB215na2duosopsg4ddnoZ3s7sd97432918768' and group: 'DEFAULT', because one already exists with this identification.`

Comment: try this code : if (sched.checkExists(job.getKey())) {sched.rescheduleJob(trigger.getKey(), trigger);
        } else {sched.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
        }

Comment: Actually what i want is to run the same job in both the nodes of a clustered server. One process should be active at once. If the active process dies, the passive should become active.  So as of now i have put the {sched.scheduleJob(job, trigger); } in try catch. And so not scheduling the job if its scheduled once. So does this looks ok?

Comment: I understand you want just one node to trigger the jobs at a time, the other node will only be active if the first goes down. The snippet I gave you in my comment will allow the second node to schedule the job, even if the first node already defined it. Try it for yourself !

Comment: Ok now i was able to start the job in one node as active and in other node as passive. If the active job dies, the passive job will become active.        But now my query is that if the job dies because of server being stopped, so will it come up when the server comes up??

Comment: as far as I remember, the job will keep on executing on the active node it is running on